# iphone SSO Facebook implementation

Tags: iphone, facebook, single-sign-on

Question regarding SSO Implementation of Facebook. I followed the instructions and added to the AppDelegate implementation code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

however, I get the error,

```
unknown receiver _viewController, did you mean UIViewController?
```

I change it to that, and I get the warning,

```
class method +facebook not found
```

I am using the tutorial located here
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to handle opening the url is implemented incorrectly.  The link you provided has the following code sample.  Which shows the application delegates `Facebook` object property calling the method `handleOpenURL`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

In the code you provided, you are attempting to call a class method called `facebook` on your instance of `_viewController`.  UIViewController doesn't have a class method called 'facebook'  this is why you're getting the warning.

```
class method + facebook not found
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, however the tutorial is not posting the video at all that I am attempting.