# IOS - Facebook SDK fbDidLogin not called -- initialize view controllers.

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I followed the Facebook SDK tutorial from Facebook step by step. I have everything working besides fbDidLogin getting called... the authorization process works fine. I've been told to do:

```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
          return [[controller facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
     }
```

from [fbDidLogin not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called)

the problem is is that I'm not exactly sure how to alloc init my view controller. Here is my .h for app delegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"


@interface fb2AppDelegate : UIResponder  <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {

    Facebook *facebook; 
    UIViewController *fb2ViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) Facebook *facebook; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *fb2ViewController;

@end
```

and the .m :

```
#import "fb2AppDelegate.h"

@implementation fb2AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize facebook;
@synthesize fb2ViewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.fb2ViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"key_here" andDelegate:self];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    } 


    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[fb2ViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)fbDidLogin {

    NSLog(@"fbdidlogin"); 

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"key_here", @"app_id",
                                   @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                                   nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

as for the view controllers... I haven't put any code in them.

the error that I am receiving is:

no visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'Facebook'

what am i doing wrong?

thx!

Comment: what do you mean by the second version of the implementation?

Comment: It doesn't work though... gives the following error: 


no visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'Facebook'    =(

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone SSO Facebook implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403697/iphone-sso-facebook-implementation)

Comment: similar problem... the answer to that question doesn't work though... and is what I'm trying to change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called

Comment: @user1392515 You need to do: [facebook handleOpenURL:url]. You are currently using facebook as a selector instead of an object.

Comment: tried that first and nothing happened... fbDidLogin never got called... then i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called ... but I cant implement the solution properly so it seems.

Comment: @user1392515 facebook.sessionDelegate = self;

Comment: where... ? in the application did launch with options?

Comment: @AlexanderNorway; put an answer up, I'll up vote.  You deserve half the credit here.

Comment: lol due to the consensus here.. AlexanderNorway put up an answer... also CodaFi I can't believe you're 15 ... that's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, You need to do:

```
[facebook handleOpenURL:url].
```

You are currently using `facebook` as a selector instead of an object.

Also.. you need to set `facebook.sessionDelegate = self`,  so that the delegate method `fbDidLogin` can get called.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user1392515 Thanks for giving me the correct answer. I didn't really expect you to to be honest. I just like to refrain from answering before Im 100% sure it solves your problem because it might keep others from reading your question when it has already been answered.

Comment: @CodaFi The same goes for you :)

Comment: Well @AlexanderNorway, it's not as though I needed the rep anyhow ;)

Comment: @CodaFi yeah, your rep is insane ^^ hehe. Thanks anyways though :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the runtime believes that your UIViewController has the class method +facebook, when in reality, that was an example singleton the other question's answer used (rather confusingly I might add).  You need to send it to an instance of the Facebook *object* and call your code from there.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
      return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
 }
```

Also remember that in order for delegate methods to be called, your objects actually has to be a delegate.  So set `facebook.sessionDelegate = self` and conform to the protocol in the header with `<FBSessionDelegate>` to silence the compiler warnings.

Comment: thx for the answer! tried that first and nothing happened... i mean that makes sense to me of course.. but fbDidLogin never gets called...

Comment: Of course not, silly.  You aren't this thing's `sessionDelegate`!

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
wish i could split the credit between you and : facebook.sessionDelegate = self; – AlexanderNorway 1 min ago